# Support different layouts sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to create the following folders for the different device screen sizes , the thing it's I create the folders layout-sw320dp and layout-sw480dp to try the small screens and mediums but when I try to select a medium screen under sw480 I can't select any, just the big ones like 7", I'll send you the screen shot so you can see:

```
 activity_actividad_login.xml(sw320dp)
   activity_actividad_login.xml(sw480dp)
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996396/2826147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the step as mention in the images , the you can easily find out the folders which you are looking for

1. Click on the dropdown at the upper left corner in the android studio and choose Project

[image]

2. Go to you app resource directory

[image]

3. then right click on the resource directory and perform the action as shown in the screenshot

[image]

4. Enter your directory name like **layout-sw600dp** in the directory name dialog box and click ok

[image]

then you will find your layout-sw600dp folder in the resource directory..

[image]

Hope , this will help you out...

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helps you. [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)